# CentOS git: command not found for non-root user

Tags: git, centos, centos7

CentOS: **centos-release-7-9.2009.1.el7.centos.x86_64**

I have installed git 2.13.0 by command:

```
rpm -U http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/7/git/x86_64/wandisco-git-release-7-2.noarch.rpm     && yum install -y git
```

In root:

```
# git --version
git version 2.13.0
```

In user (non-root):

```
$ git --version
bash: git: command not found
```

How to install git for user (non-root)?

Comment: `echo $PATH` for root and non-root users.

Comment: Manually added path to ~/.bashrc, not working: 

which git
/usr/local/bin/git

$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/sites/.local/bin:/sites/bin:/sites/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin/git

# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/.local/bin:/root/bin:/root/usr/local/bin:/root/bin

Comment: After changing PATH in `~/.bashrc` the file must be sourced into open shells. Or new shells must be started.

Comment: source ~/.bashrc or restart shell not worked for me :(

Comment: `which git` with the new PATH. `ls -l /usr/local/bin/git` ? `/usr/local/bin/git --version` ? `git --version` ?

Comment: $ which git
bash: /usr/bin/which: No such file or directory https://prnt.sc/bSjFpI57DXAg

Answer (score -1):

If you do not have access to any application you have installed as root and your user has sudo privileges try the following

```
#sudo git --version
```

The system may ask you for password to execute command under sudo with higher privileges